MLFLOW Artifacts stored in remote storage not showing on UI
Set up:


tracking server openstack instance
mlflow tracking database on second openstack instance
traring on on-prem HPC node


Tracking server start
python3 -m mlflow server --dev --app-name oidc-auth --host 0.0.0.0
--port 8080 --backend-store-uri postgresql+psycopg2://$DB_USERNAME:$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_IP_ADDRESS:5432/$DB_NAME

Experiment (i need artifact_location because each research group will want to use their on remote directory
# Create a new experiment
    experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_name)
    if experiment is None:
        exp = mlflow.create_experiment(experiment_name, artifact_location='/lustre/scratch127/mlops_artifacts')
        set_experiment = mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_id=exp)
    else:
        set_experiment = mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name)

From logs

First Experiment Elastic Net
Name: exp_EL_research
Experiment_id: 8
Artifact Location: /lustre/scratch127/mlops_artifacts
Active run id is fff785c73a814fc89102ed7a486de96d
Active run name is bedecked-grub-472
Artifact URI is /lustre/scratch127/mlops_artifacts/fff785c73a814fc89102ed7a486de96d/artifacts

first question why artifact_uri is not /lustre/scratch127/mlops_artifacts/8/fff785c73a814fc89102ed7a486de96d/artifacts ??
# Log the model
mlflow.sklearn.log_model(sk_model=lr, artifact_path=artifact_path, registered_model_name=model_name
fff785c73a814fc89102ed7a486de96d
└── artifacts
        └── 8
               ├── conda.yaml
               ├── metadata
               │   ├── conda.yaml
               │   ├── MLmodel
               │   ├── python_env.yaml
               │   └── requirements.txt
               ├── MLmodel
               ├── model.pkl
               ├── python_env.yaml
               └── requirements.txt


I believe the issue is that the tracking server does not have access to the store filesystem.
